# Security of PDF reader software

Tags: pdf

Are there any studies regarding the security of PDF viewer software from different vendors? I try to find the most secure reader.

Answer (score 3):

[PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) has been developed in javascript and is inside the ([very secure](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2025153/firefoxs-pdf-viewer-may-boost-security-by-boring-hackers.html)) js sandbox. Chrome has one of the most secure js sandboxes, so you might want [pdf.js in chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm).

[Evince is very easily exploitable](http://www.mupuf.org/blog/2014/05/16/who-do-i-design-security-for/). I don't know which part the fuzz-testing included, but Evince bases on [poppler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_%28software%29), so that may make Okular insecure, too.

Comment: What about using Chrome PDF Viewer that is bundled with the browser ( chrome://plugins/ ) - is it safe?

Comment: @MarekAndreansky it runs in a sandbox too, so it can be used for normal use, burt pdf.js in chrome seems to be even safer.

Comment: Why is pdf.js more secure?

Comment: Its in an additional sandbox.

Comment: Do you have any security information about Sumatra PDF viewer? http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html Even thou pdf.js in Chrome is safer it allocates 26 MB of memory compared to Sumatra that allocates only 6 MB